# am trying to send a HashMap<ArrayList<FilterInput>, Integer> in Response.ok(x).build(); returning half of the result in response.getBody(), why?

Tags: spring, response

I am trying to send a   `HashMap<ArrayList<FilterInput>, Integer>` in `Response.ok(x).build();` returning half of the result in `response.getBody()`, why?

```
ArrayList<FilterInput> hfi = new ArrayList<FilterInput>();
        ArrayList<CountByTime> hcbt = new ArrayList<CountByTime>();
        HashMap<ArrayList<FilterInput>, Integer> hficbi = new HashMap<ArrayList<FilterInput>, Integer>();
        FilterInput fi =new FilterInput();
        fi.setCustomerId("1");
        fi.setEntityId("test");
        CountByTime c = new CountByTime();
        c.setCount(1);
        c.setTime("MAY");
        hcbt.add(c);
        CountByTime c1 = new CountByTime();
        c1.setCount(2);;
        c1.setTime("MAY1");
        hcbt.add(c1);
        CountByTime c2 = new CountByTime();
        c2.setCount(3);;
        c2.setTime("MAY2");
        hcbt.add(c2);
        fi.setCountByTimeList(hcbt);
        hfi.add(fi);
        System.out.println(hfi);
        FilterInput f2 =new FilterInput();
        ArrayList<CountByTime> hcbt2 = new ArrayList<CountByTime>();
        f2.setCustomerId("2");
        f2.setEntityId("test1");
        CountByTime c3 = new CountByTime();
        c3.setCount(6);;
        c3.setTime("MAY3");
        hcbt2.add(c3);
        CountByTime c4 = new CountByTime();
        c4.setCount(4);;
        c4.setTime("MAY4");
        hcbt2.add(c4);
        CountByTime c5 = new CountByTime();
        c5.setCount(5);;
        c5.setTime("MAY5");
        hcbt2.add(c5);
        f2.setCountByTimeList(hcbt2);
        hfi.add(f2);
        hficbi.put(hfi, 0);
        /*CountByTime ct = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            fi = new FilterInput();
            fi.setCustomerId(sc.next());
            fi.setEntityId(sc.next());
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    ct = new CountByTime();
                    ct.setCount(sc.nextInt());
                    ct.setTime(sc.next());
                    hcbt.add(ct);
                }
        fi.setCountByTimeList(hcbt);
        hfi.add(fi);
        }
        hficbi.put(hfi, 0);*/
        System.out.println(hficbi);
 return Response.ok(hficbi).build();
```

expecting the response in body like this:

```
{[FilterInput [customerId=1, entityId=test, countByTimeList=[CountByTime [time=MAY, count=1], CountByTime [time=MAY1, count=2], CountByTime [time=MAY2, count=3]]], FilterInput [customerId=2, entityId=test1, countByTimeList=[CountByTime [time=MAY3, count=6], CountByTime [time=MAY4, count=4], CountByTime [time=MAY5, count=5]]]]=0}
```

but getting this much only:

```
    {[FilterInput [customerId=1, entityId=test ]
FilterInput [customerId=2, entityId=test1 ]}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"half of the result"* exactly?

Comment: ideally output should be this:
{[FilterInput [customerId=1, entityId=test, countByTimeList=[CountByTime [time=MAY, count=1], CountByTime [time=MAY1, count=2], CountByTime [time=MAY2, count=3]]], FilterInput [customerId=2, entityId=test1, countByTimeList=[CountByTime [time=MAY3, count=6], CountByTime [time=MAY4, count=4], CountByTime [time=MAY5, count=5]]]]=0}
but in response m getting {[FilterInput [customerId=1, entityId=test ]
FilterInput [customerId=2, entityId=test1 ]} only :(

Comment: Include all the relevant information directly in the question by editing it, and remember apply relevant formatting to make it readable.